# MongoDB finding nested sub documents with multiple conditions in same key

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection where I have many items of the following format

```
{
   '_id': ObjectId(),
   'info': [{
              'type': "type1",
              'foo': foo
           },
           {
              'type': "type2",
              'bar': bar
           },
           {
              'type': "type3",
              'foo': foo
           }]
}
```

I'd like to be able to find all documents that contain type1 AND type2 subdocuments, and have them projected to only include type1 and type2.

So response would look like:

```
[{ '_id': ObjectId(), 'info': [{'type': "type1", 'foo': foo}, {'type': "type2", 'bar': bar}]}, ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

`yourTable.find({ $or: [{ "info.type": "type1" }, { "info.type": "type2" }, { "info.type": "type3" }] })`

you could try something like this.

Here is the link:
[1]: https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/use-mongoose-to-find-in-an-array-of-objects-1206

Comment: This returns all the documents that have type1 OR type2, I need documents that info has a subdocument of type1 AND a subdocument of type2.  I also need the projection.